# Отсутствует перевод соглашения для модераторов

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Непереведенный текст [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Ссылка на соглашение получена со страницы [Кто такие модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: Думаю, юридические документы не подлежат переводу. Если только в ознакомительных целях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin т.е. модератор руSO должен в обязательном порядке владеть английским на уровне понимания юр.документов? К тому же документ расположен в секции `ru.stackoverflow.com`, а это вроде как что-то должно подразумевать. И, кстати, [вот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2109/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-moderator-agreement). Можно закрывать как копию.

Comment: Вот я помнил же, что уже где-то это видел ))

Comment: Насчёт знания языка - я даже и не задумывался, что это может стать препятствием для кого-то. Но ведь может, теоретически.

Comment: @NickVolynkin прямо как я с кнопкой [`отменить`](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3794/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0#comment12246_3796)